# Finite $p$-group in which all its maximal subgroups are cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group, $|G|=p^n$. Let $M_1,\dots,M_r$ be all the maximal subgroups and suppose they are cyclic.
Why is $\Phi(G)\le Z(G)$? $\Phi(G)$ is the Frattini subgroup. I have no idea where to start.

Any hint would be appreciated! Thank you all

Comment: Every element is contained in a maximal subgroup. (Not true, but if not, then the whole group is cyclic.) Every maximal subgroup is cyclic, and hence abelian. Every maximal subgroup contains $\Phi(G)$. So every element commutes with every element in $\Phi(G)$.

Comment: Many thanks Derek.

Comment: One more question: I read that as a consequence of the fact that $\Phi(G)\le Z(G)$, we have that $\Phi(G)\le Z(M_i),\;\; \Phi(G)\le Z(M_j)\Rightarrow \Phi(G)\le Z(\langle M_i,M_j\rangle)$. Why?

Answer as an answer, not as a comment: I'd be happy to give you a +1 and a "correct answer" :-)

Comment: Seems like there's something wrong with the question. If every $x \in \Phi(G)$ is in $Z(G)$, then they definitely commute with every element. Are you sure you phrased the question correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $g \in \Phi(G)$ .

Every maximal proper subgroup of a $p$-group is normal and has index $p$, so if $ i\neq j$ we have $$M_i M_j = G$$ because $M_i M_j $ is a subgroup and $M_i \subsetneq M_i M_j $.

Thus if $x \in G $ there exist $g_i \in M_i \ , \ \ g_j \in M_j$ such that $$x = g_i g_j$$

All the maximal subgroups are abelian  because they are cyclic, the Frattini subgroup is contained in every maximal subgroup by definition and so $g$ commutes with $g_i$ and $g_j$, thus $$gx = g g_i g_j = g_ig_j g = xg$$

This means that $$g \in Z(G)$$